# How to Run Python Code 30 Sec before Every 5th Minute

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

I have a python program which I want to execute exactly 30 seconds before every 5th Minute and need to run for 30 seconds only.

Comment: This is less of a python question and more of an operating system question. Perhaps you could ask about task scheduling on something like: https://superuser.com/ https://apple.stackexchange.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/ depending on what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than looping and testing if it's the right time over and over again, it's better to calculate the amount of time needed to wait, and sleep until then so the processor can go off and do other things. To do this we still use the `datetime` module and just a bit of simple math.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from time import sleep

#Calculating sleep interval
t = dt.now()
#seconds in the hour
sec = t.second + t.minute*60
#seconds since the last 5 min interval
sec = sec % 300
#until the next 5 min interval
sec = 300 - sec
#30 sec before that
sec = sec - 30
#if negative we're within 30 sec of 5 minute interval so goto next one
if sec < 0:
    sec = sec + 300
sleep(sec)

while True: #loop forever
    #with a little re-arranging and boolean math, this can all be condensed to:
    t = dt.now()
    s = (t.second + 60*t.minute) % 300
    sleep(270 - s + 300 * (s >= 270))
    #yourFunction()
```

For very simple cases this should work. If at any point your program crashes, or if the computer re-boots, or a myriad of other reasons, It would be better to use something built in to the OS which will re-start the program automatically, and can handle other conditions such as setting sleep timers, or only executing if a particular user is logged in. On Windows this is task scheduler, on Linux this is typically cron, and OSX is launchd (at least according to developer.apple.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this code indefintley, I'd suggest you look at following Aaron's adivce at look at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/),  [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/).

However, if you were going to write this in Python, you could use the `datetime` module and find the time that's elapsed.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time


def your_function(t1):
    i = 0
    # For the next 30 seconds, run your function
    while (datetime.now() - t1).seconds =< 30:
        i += 1
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)


# Run indefintely
while True:

    # Record the current time
    t1 = datetime.now()
    while t1:

        # Find the elapsed time in seconds 
        # If the difference is 270 seconds (4 minutes and 30 seconds)
        if (datetime.now()-t1).seconds == 270:
                your_function(t1)

            # Remove t1 and start at the top of the loop again
            t1 = None
```

Comment: Some things I'd change if I were implementing cron in python: You can't specifically rely on your `if` statement happening on the exact second, so you should use a relative operator: `> or < or >= or <=`. Timekeeping is nowhere near guaranteed, so you should compare to clock time rather than just an interval of 5 min to prevent drift. Really, I'd just calculate the delta to the next interval once and `time.sleep` for that long. You'll be at the mercy of the OS scheduling the thread to run no matter what you do, so you might as well sleep until then to save cpu cycles.